# Titanium Alloy - unable to disable Label inside Tabbedbar using id

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I have a TabbedBar which contains Labels and inside it have Label whose enable property I need to change in .js file through coding. I have tried setting id of that particular label and have used. `$.lblProf.enabled = false;` in .js file. Its throwing error:

> Undefined is not an object(evaluating '$.lblProf.enabled = false')

demo.xml

```
<TabbedBar id="tabbedBar" platform="ios" backgroundColor="#369" top="44dp" height="30dp" width="300" index="0" onClick="tabBarClick">
   <Labels> 
      <Label>Details</Label>
      <Label>Photos</Label>
      <Label>Documents</Label>
      <Label id="tabProfile">Profile</Label>                        
   </Labels>
</TabbedBar>
```

demo.js

```
$.tabProfile.enabled = true;
```

If I am trying to disable directly i.e

```
<Label id="lblProf" enabled="false">
```

its working fine.

Comment: Aren't you missing the ID in your Labels element in demo.xml?

Comment: Thanks for you response visola. So even if I am adding id in Labels element how to access lblProf in demo.js ?

Comment: It looks like your doing the right thing. Maybe your missing something else. Is that all your code? Aren't you missing some elements like Alloy or Window? All samples I've seen have them.

Comment: visola. This is the complete code that I am having.

Answer (score 0):

As @visola mentioned, your labels need an ID in order to access them programmatically. Otherwise, Alloy gives them an auto-generated ID which is usually unhelpful to humans.

xml

```
<TabbedBar id="tabbedBar" platform="ios" backgroundColor="#369" top="44dp" height="30dp" width="300" index="0" onClick="tabBarClick">
   <Labels id='labelsList'> 
      <Label id='details'>Details</Label>
      <Label id='photos'>Photos</Label>
      <Label id='documents'>Documents</Label>
      <Label id='tabProfile'>Profile</Label>                        
   </Labels>
</TabbedBar>
```

As for the tabProfile assignment, `$` is the top-level object on the page hierarchy. So, `$.tabProfile` does not exist. That's why changing it has no effect. You need to drill down further into the page `$.TabbedBar.Labels.Label`. With that said, `Label` has no `enabled` property. So, your app throws the `undefined` error.

I would review the [Titanium.UI.iOS.TabbedBar](http://file:///Users/mjstelly/Library/Application%20Support/Dash/DocSets/Appcelerator_Titanium/Appcelerator%20Titanium.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/html/Titanium.UI.iOS.TabbedBar.html%20%22Titanium.UI.iOS.TabbedBar') documentation for more examples. It appears that you'll need to simulate disabling them by changing the color, to light gray for example, and then setting `touchEnabled` to false.

Hope that helps you move forward.